# Enabling Things iPhone legacy sync messes up recurring tasks and areas - can this be avoided?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to enable [Bonjour Legacy Sync](http://support.culturedcode.com/customer/portal/articles/677577) in [Things iPhone](http://culturedcode.com/things/iphone/) (so that I can sync with an old and unused version of Things Mac on Snow Leopard).

Having followed the instructions linked above, when I restart Things in Things 1 mode it shows lots of instances of a recurring task in Today which weren't there before, and doesn't show a large number of changes I've recently made to Areas.

I've now turned off Things 1 mode and restored the Things 2 database. **Is there a way to enable legacy sync without disordering my tasks and losing some recent changes?**

*Running Things 2.2.3 on iOS 6.1.1 (deliberate non-upgrade to avoid battery problems on a beaten up 4S).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompt response via email from Julia at Cultured Code to my support request using the [feedback form](https://culturedcode.com/contact/) answers the question:

> When you revert to Things 1 mode, the data from Things 2 cannot be
>   converted to the older database format. There should be a note warning
>   about this when converting to Things 1 mode; if not, I apologize for
>   the confusion this caused.
>
> Basically, if you want to have the to-dos from Things 2 in Things 1,
>   you have to re-enter them manually. Since this downgrade path is one
>   that only very few customers chose to take, we didn’t spend time on
>   implementing a downgrade path for the data.